# How to fix a System.InvalidCastException after deployment in production environment

Tags: vb.net, caching, datatable, boolean, dbnull

I am working on an existing code and I have made some change. While I have added some new columns in the database table, the code uses cache to store data from the DataTable. The cache time is set to 15 minutes. Now the problem I am getting here is that when I deployed my code to the production environment, it gave me the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Boolean'

I have tried almost everything, from adding IfDBNull() to giving a default value "False" to the table. Since, the default value of the table is set to zero, the value of new column added will be "False" by default in the database. But I am still getting this error. I am suspecting that it has something to do with the Cache I am using on server side. Here is the code in business logic.

```
  Dim ds As DataSet

  If HttpRuntime.Cache("MyCacheKeyName") Is Nothing = True Then
      ds = New DataAccess().GetDataSet(MLCulture, UserStateID:=UserStateID)
      HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("MyCacheKeyName")
      HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("MyCacheKeyName", ds, Nothing, System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, Nothing)
    Else
      ds = HttpRuntime.Cache("MyCacheKeyName")
    End If

    Return ds
```

This is the new code that I added with my change:

```
<div class="divStyle" <%# If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(IfDBNull(Container.DataItem("NewBoolean"), False), IfDBNull(Container.DataItem("NewColumnDateTime"), Utility.NullValues.NullDate), IfDBNull(Container.DataItem("NewColumnDateTime"), Utility.NullValues.NullDate), Container.DataItem("ColumnString")), "style='display:none'", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Container.DataItem("ColumnString")), "", "style='color:" & Container.DataItem("ColumnString") & ";'"))%>><%#Container.DataItem("ColumnString")%></div>
```

Comment: You don't need to type `If HttpRuntime.Cache("MyCacheKeyName") Is Nothing = True Then`, simply,  `If HttpRuntime.Cache("MyCacheKeyName") Is Nothing Then` suffices. Can you mark in your code on which line you get the error?

Comment: @AConfusedSimpleton Actually I am not getting the error on local environments. Error occurs only on the live production environment and the code is working fine on local environments. I can share the Error message and Stack Trace if that helps you understand the issue.

Comment: @AFriend the Cache code is included in the question I posted. The problem is that now the data table in DataSet "ds" has changed and has 3 new columns, and after these changes the above mentioned error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> HttpRuntime.Cache("MyCacheKeyName").ToString()